# Python 3, multithreading - getting data into main module as each thread finishes

Tags: python, class, variables

The following code executes two threads (multithread), each with different time delays so that each thread will finish at a different time.

Once both threads are finished module **display1.py** issues a print statement saying they are BOTH finished.

**I would like module display1.py to issue a 'finished' statement for EACH thread AS EACH thread finishes**

How can i do this ... amendments to my working code appreciated! I'd like to change as little of the current code as possible so a better form of variable transfer between the two modules might be what I'm after

**display1.py**

```
from threads1 import *


manager = ThreadManager()
manager.start(False)

print (manager.GetResults())
```

**threads1.py**

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class ThreadManager:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self, answer):
        self.answer = answer
        thread_refs = []

        t1 = MyThread(70, 'Not finished')
        t1.daemon = True
        t1.start()

        t2 = MyThread(2, 'Not finished')
        t2.daemon = True
        t2.start()

        while True:
          if t1.AskFinished == 'Finished' and t2.AskFinished == 'Finished':  #If I break the loop after EACH site, Only the first to finish will be sent via GetResults to display1.py
            global results
            results = [t1.AskFinished, t2.AskFinished]
            print("Both Finished")
            break

    def GetResults(self):
      global results
      return(results)


class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, SleepWait, AskFinished):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.SleepWait = SleepWait
        self.AskFinished = AskFinished


    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.SleepWait)
        self.AskFinished = 'Finished'
```

Comment: So far no one has actually answered the question which I was quite clear about. They have all managed to talk about everything EXCEPT the answer to my question ... aside from senderle who acknowledged the questions existence ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here (entering a very tight check loop in the main thread) is a very naive approach to threading in many languages, but especially in python where GIL contention will just slow the threads down a great bit.

What is a better idea is instead using queue.Queue to push info when a thread is completed. This allows the main thread to block on the queue instead, which is less CPU intensive as well as allowing you to know (out of order) which one is finished.

The changes you would need to make:

at the top of the module `threads1.py`:

```
import queue

finished_queue = queue.Queue()
```

in your start():

```
num_finished = 0
while True:
    info = finished_queue.get()
    num_finished += 1
    if info is t1:
        print("t1 finished")
    else:
        print("t2 finished")
    if num_finished == 2:
        global results
        results = [t1.AskFinished, t2.AskFinished]
        print("Both Finished")
        break
```

and finally in run():

```
def run(self):
    time.sleep(self.SleepWait)
    self.AskFinished = 'Finished'
    finished_queue.put(self)
```

Some more fundamental modifications I'd make is actually pushing the result into the queue and then fetching the results out, skipping the extra step before GetResults.  Furthermore, if GetResults had to stay, I'd pass them through a field on `self` e.g. `self.results = [t1.AskFinished, t2.AskFinished]`

Comment: thats very much, yes I don't have much xp in classes or threading so i appreciate you response. I'll give this a go tonight

Comment: Is this code going to print("t1 finished") or print("t2 finished") from display1.py? I need it too. After Each thread is done. The string variable "t1 finished" is transferred to display1.py and printed there

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

Ok, so you want to know more about how to have `display1.py` print the results. It would be helpful if you could explain why it matters, because that might make a difference in how you should do this, but here's a first approach:

```
# threads1.py
from threading import Thread
import time

class ThreadManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.threads = {}

    def start(self):
        t1 = MyThread(4)
        t1.daemon = True
        t1.start()
        self.threads[1] = t1

        t2 = MyThread(1)
        t2.daemon = True
        t2.start()
        self.threads[2] = t2

    def is_alive(self, thread_id):
        return self.threads[thread_id].is_alive()

    def GetResults(self):    # or you could just access results directly
        return self.results

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, SleepWait):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.SleepWait = SleepWait

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.SleepWait)
```

And then...

```
# display1.py
from threads1 import *

manager = ThreadManager()
manager.start()

t1_state = t2_state = True
while manager.is_alive(1) or manager.is_alive(2):
  time.sleep(1)
  if manager.is_alive(1) != t1_state:
    print("t1 finished")
    t1_state = manager.is_alive(1)
  if manager.is_alive(2) != t2_state:
    print("t2 finished")
    t2_state = manager.is_alive(2)
  if not manager.is_alive(1) and not manager.is_alive(2):
    print("Both Finished")
    break
```

You should eventually consider using a Queue as suggested by Crast; but let's focus on getting this right first.

**Original Post**:

There are a number of problems with this code.

First, you should use `t1.is_alive()` to check if a thread is finished. There's no need to reimplement it with `AskFinished`.

Second, the `while True:` loop in threads1.py is doing nothing at a **furious rate** while it waits for your threads to terminate. Take a look at the cpu usage while this is running if you don't believe me. You should throw a `time.sleep(1)` statement in there.

Third, why are you using a global var to return your results? That's a really strange thing to do. Just store it in self!

And finally, why does `display1.py` have to print the messages? Why can't `thread1.py` do that?

With these four points in mind, here's a thread1.py that works more sensibly:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class ThreadManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = None

    def start(self, answer): # why is "answer" here?
        self.answer = answer
        thread_refs = []

        t1 = MyThread(4, 'Not finished')
        t1.daemon = True
        t1.start()

        t2 = MyThread(1, 'Not finished')
        t2.daemon = True
        t2.start()

        t1_state = t2_state = True
        while t1.is_alive() or t2.is_alive():
          time.sleep(1)
          if t1.is_alive() != t1_state:
            print("t1 finished")
            t1_state = t1.is_alive()
          if t2.is_alive() != t2_state:
            print("t2 finished")
            t2_state = t2.is_alive()
          if not t1.is_alive() and not t2.is_alive():
            self.results = [t1.AskFinished, t2.AskFinished]
            print("Both Finished")
            break

    def GetResults(self):    # or you could just access results directly
        return self.results


class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, SleepWait, AskFinished):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.SleepWait = SleepWait
        self.AskFinished = AskFinished


    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.SleepWait)
        self.AskFinished = 'Finished'
```

Now, this still doesn't do exactly what you wanted, because you asked for `display.py` to do the displaying. To make that work, you'd have to put your `while True` loop in `display.py` and add an `ThreadManager.is_alive()` method that `display.py` could use to check whether a thread is alive or not. If you want to see how to do that let me know.

Comment: t1.is_alive() .. cool ... yes I know its not pro code but then I never said i was pro xD

Thanks for your help, i will definitely make these changes.

Comment: if you could show how I can get display.py to display instead of threads.py that would be great

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much for talking to time to answer the question asked! Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with threading but since no answers yet ill give it a shot.

In this:
Cant you just add two if statements before hand?

```
    while True:
      if t1.askFinished == 'Finished':
         print("t1 Finished")
      if t2.askFinished == 'Finished':
         print("t2 Finished")
      if t1.AskFinished == 'Finished' and t2.AskFinished == 'Finished':  #If I break the loop after EACH site, Only the first to finish will be sent via GetResults to display1.py
        global results
        results = [t1.AskFinished, t2.AskFinished]
        print("Both Finished")
        break
```

edit: I tried changing your code as little as possible... it's not very well written though tbh. (No offense)

Comment: Ah I don't want the response to come from threads1.py ... print("t2 Finished") should print from display1.py module

Comment: just FYI, this prints "t2 finished" over and over again until t1 terminates (or vice versa).